# How to use database table header for html <th> table header tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-table

I'm new to PHP. I use the code (below) to print a MySQL table as an HTML table.

However my code prints the table headers from the database.

**How can I print HTML table header in hard coded format using the `<th>header</th>` tags and print the all rows from the table?**

Thanks!

```
<?php
 $db_host = 'localhost';
 $db_user = 'my user';
 $db_pwd = 'my pwd';

 $database = 'my db';
 $table = 'subcontractor';

 if (!mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pwd))
     die("Can't connect to database");

 if (!mysql_select_db($database))
     die("Can't select database");

 // sending query
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
 if (!$result) {
     die("Query to show fields from table failed");
 }

 $fields_num = mysql_num_fields($result);

 echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped mb-none' id='datatable-tabletools' data-swf-path='assets/vendor/jquery-datatables/extras/TableTools/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf' >";

 // printing table headers
 echo "<thead>";
 for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
 {
     $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
     echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
 }
 echo "</thead>";
 // printing table rows
 while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
 {
     echo "<tbody>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "</thead>";

     // $row is array... foreach( .. ) puts every element
     // of $row to $cell variable
     foreach($row as $cell)
         echo "<td>$cell</td>";

     echo "</tr>";
     echo "</tbody>";
 }
 mysql_free_result($result);
 ?>
```

Comment: so rip out the database output and `echo "<th>text you want</th>"` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thank you works perfect. Is there a way to make PHP skip a column from the table on the DB? Thanks –

Yes, just change the Query

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM {$table}");
```

for example by

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`,`email`,`address` FROM {$table}");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the headers by removing these lines of code.

```
for($i=0; $i<$fields_num; $i++)
{   
   $field = mysql_fetch_field($result);
   echo "<th>{$field->name}</th>";
}
```

Replace the above lines for example by:

```
echo "<thead>";
echo "<th>My Header 1</th>";
echo "<th>My Header 2</th>";
echo "</thead>";
```